# Predictions in SageMaker ::: Writing Function To Split Big Data-frame Into Batches For Predictions

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, batch-processing

I am using amazon SageMaker for model training and predictions. However, I  have issues InvokeEndpoint does still have a 5MB limit per request.

However, I over million rows as distinct inputs, I know I should look at sending separate requests for each of them, or splitting the input into some batch size that fits comfortably under the limit, and sending each batch as a separate request (possibly in parallel to the same endpoint).

```
### Making predictions based on 1 dataframe of 500 rows
### aproximately 500 rows are ~500MB

    num_predict_rows <- 500 
    test_sample <- as.matrix(gender_test[1:num_predict_rows, ])
    dimnames(test_sample)[[2]] <- NULL

    library(stringr)
    predictions <- model_endpoint$predict(data_tbl_test)
    predictions <- str_split(predictions, pattern = ',', simplify = TRUE)
    predictions <- as.numedimnames(data_tbl_test)[[2]] <- NULLric(predictions)

    data_tbl_pred <- cbind(predicted_sample = predictions, data_tbl_test[1:num_predict_rows, ])
```

My questions are

how I can write a function

- which split the input data frame to below than 500 rows (<5MB)
- so I will have **n** batches of the data
- then I can do predictions based on the above code for all batches
- finally, I should have a combined data frame with all predictions for **n** bacthes

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want each batch to have exactly 500 rows or around 500 rows (about the largest number of rows which are less than 5 MB)?

Comment: @mickey yes I want to have exactly 500 rows. as I tried more than that exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using SageMaker Batch Transform instead for your use-case above? It takes care of streaming your data from S3 to the inference container and supports a few ways to split up your data.

Please see 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html for an overview. Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html if you are bringing your own inference container to know the nitty-gritty.

A few sample notebooks:

1. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/4cc457faf4873c0ce674b6b5f857b5ee85967bf6/advanced_functionality/batch_transform
2. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/c80657daa9d42b7c9b12729d6fa4b825fd980730/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/Scikit-learn%20Estimator%20Example%20With%20Batch%20Transform.ipynb
3. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/7a2618a669a00b08458504c0055f0a13dd5ccfd7/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_mnist/mxnet_mnist_with_batch_transform.ipynb

If you have detailed questions / require support for specific transform jobs, please reach out on AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285&start=0

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tweak this to structure the output as you want, but if I'm understanding your code, this should do predictions for each `batch` and then the results are stored in `all_preds`.

```
library(stringr)

# some initialization
N <- NROW(data_tbl_test)
num_predict_rows <- 500 
n <- ceiling(N / num_predict_rows)
k <- 1   # This should be the number of columns in model_endpoint$predict(...)
all_preds = matrix(0, NROW(data_tbl_test), k)   # where the predictions will be stored

# get batch indices
ind <- rep(list(NULL), n)
for (i in 1:n)
    ind[[i]] <- seq((i-1)*500+1, min(i*500, N)) 

# predict on each batch
for (i in 1:n){
    batch = data_tbl_test[ind[[i]],]
    predictions <- model_endpoint$predict(batch)
    predictions <- str_split(predictions, pattern = ',', simplify = TRUE)
    predictions <- as.numedimnames(batch)[[2]] <- NULLric(predictions)
    all_preds[ind[[i]],] = predictions
    }
```

Comment: @nickey thanks very much indeed for your prompt reply. however, maybe I was not clear. what I want function should take a data frame (say a million rows), break them down in batches and these batches then will be input for predictions and then I assemble all predictions from each batch into a single file. so basically repeating the process I have in the code for all batches. then combining all results in one big file as an output. cheers

Comment: @JamesTaylor, I edited the answer. Is that what you're looking for? You mention assembling the results into a single file. Are you looking for `write.table`?